# C# Defining the size of an array contained in an arraylist

Tags: c#, forms

I define the arraylist on my form2, sending it using the constructor to form 3, where it is filled.  However, I want the internal array's size to be user defined.
How would i go about doing this?

Looks like this for now, but it doesn't work.

```
 private void bCapturar2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     int k=0;
     k=int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
     ((paciente)Datos[i]).num_asist = k;
     lAsistentes.Visible = true;
     tbNom_Asist.Visible = true;
     ((paciente)Datos[i]).asistentes = new string[((paciente)Datos[i]).num_asist];
     bCapturar2.Visible = false;
 }
```

Comment: assuming asistentes is an ArrayList, it makes sense because array of string is not a subclass of ArrayList then you should get "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'System.Collections.ArrayList'". What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It's worth noting that ArrayList isn't used much since List<T> was introduced.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the capacity for your ArrayList on declaration

```
var tenItemArrayList = new ArrayList(10);
```

If *asistentes* is an ArrayList, you still can change the value for capacity that way...

```
((paciente)Datos[i]).asistentes.Capacity = ((paciente)Datos[i]).num_asist;
```

However the new capacity cannot be less than the current. Otherwise you'll get an exception.

Comment: Asistentes is an array of string contained within an arraylist, asistentes size is user determined.

Comment: Setting capacity in advance makes your ArrayList more efficient. If you keep adding items after exceeding capacity, it still works but the entire collection is being copied and generated again every time.